# ¿Como puedo agregar valores a una lista que está en una clase en python?

Tags: python, poo, clase, herencia

Tengo un dolor de cabeza y es que quiero saber como puedo agregarle valores a una lista que está en una claseen python. Intento agregarle el valor a la lista y la lista siempre me sale vacía, intento heredar el código de otra clase que tengo y tampoco me deja, se que puedo, pero no se la sintaxis correcta para quitarme esta piedra del zapato. Ayuda!

```
class Libro():
    disponible= True
    def __init__ (self, titulo, autor, editorial, isbn, año_publicacion, num_ejemplares):
        self.titulo= titulo
        self.autor= autor
        self.editorial= editorial
        self.isbn= isbn
        self.año_publicacion= año_publicacion
        self.num_ejemplares= num_ejemplares
        print("Se ha registrado el libro", titulo)

    def prestar_libro(self):
        if self.num_ejemplares> 0:
            self.num_ejemplares= self.num_ejemplares -1
            print(f"Quedan disponibles:", self.num_ejemplares, "ejemplares de este libro.")
        if self.num_ejemplares==0:
            print(f"No quedan disponibles ejemplares del libro", self.titulo)
            self.dispobible= False
        
    def devolver_libro(self):
        self.num_ejemplares= self.num_ejemplares + 1
        print(f"Cantidad de ejemplares disponibles: ", self.num_ejemplares)
        #if self.num_ejemplares>0:
            #self.dispobible= True
            #print("Quedan", self.dispobible, "ejemplares disponibles.")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Con el autor",{self.autor}, "y el editorial", {self.editorial},"."

        
l= Libro ("Soy un libro", "Miqueas", "Santillana", 10402, 2023, 10)

class Biblioteca():
    lista_libros=[]
    def __init__(self, lista_libros=[]):
        self.lista_libros= lista_libros
        self.lista_libros.append(b)
        print(self.lista_libros)
        
b=Biblioteca("Soy un libro", "Miqueas", "Santillana", 10402, 2023, 10)
```

Aquí les dejo el código a ver si me puede ayudar con esto por favor, no sé como heredar los mismos valores que le doy a la clase de arriba.

Comment: cual es el mensaje de error que aparece?

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

estás teniendo unos pequeños errores conceptuales:

Un libro tiene un autor, una editorial, año de publicación, etc, que están bien determinados en tu ****init****.

La clase **Libro** debe tener métodos relacionados con estos atributos:

```
def setAutor( autor ):
   blabla

def getAutor();
    blalba
```

etc.

**no** tiene **devolver_libro** ni **prestar_libro** son métodos de la clase **Biblioteca**

La clase quedaría más o menos así:

```
class Libro():

    def __init__ ( self, titulo, autor, editorial, isbn, año_publicacion, num_ejemplares ):
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.autor = autor
        # otros
        print("Se ha registrado el libro", titulo)   

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Con el autor",{self.autor}, "y el editorial", {self.editorial},"."
```

La clase Biblioteca:

```
class Biblioteca():

    def __init__( self, lista_libros ):
        self.lista_libros = lista_libros
    
    def agregarLibro( self, libro ):
        self.lista_libros.append( libro )

    def quitarLibro( self, libro ):
        blabla

    def prestar_libro( self, libro ):
        if libro in lista_libros:
            print( "Puedo prestar este libro" )
        else:
            print( "No quedan disponibles ejemplares del libro" )
        
    def devolver_libro( self. libro ):
        agregarLibro( libro )

    def __str__(self):
        print( lista_libros )
```

Creo la lista, creo un libro, creo la biblioteca y agrego el libro a la biblioteca...

```
lista = []             
L = Libro( "Soy un libro", "Miqueas", "Santillana", 10402, 2023, 10 )   
B = Biblioteca( lista )
B.agregarLibro( A )
```

Está claro que este no pretende ser el código final, he obviado las cantidades restantes, etc, es solo a modo orientativo.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias Marce por tu respuesta, de verdad que me ayudas bastante con esto, es que estoy entrando en la POO ahora y se me hace un poco incomodo y más con la sintaxis. Gracias de verdad.

Comment: Un placer maestro, no te sientas solo, todos nos desorientamos un poco al empezar POO.

Comment: 

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema no está en la forma de heredar elementos, más bien es un pequeño problema de concepto sobre cuando se necesita heredar y cuando se necesita contener elementos de cierto tipo.

En primer lugar, en el método `def __str__(self):` de la clase `Libro` debes devolver un `string` pero al separarlo por comas estás devolviendo una tupla por lo que debería modificarse, agregué un poco de texto para que al imprimir un libro se muestre un poco más de información:

```
return f"Libro: {self.titulo}, con el autor: {self.autor}, y el editorial: {self.editorial}."
```

Debes notar como todo está encerrado en un único par de comillas dobles.

Para que funcione mejor, vamos a cambiar el método `__str__` por [`__repr__`](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-repr-method-in-python) que devuelve una representación de la clase como `string`.

En la clase `Biblioteca` no necesitas heredar, más bien lo que necesitas es que la clase contenga elementos de tipo `Libro`. La biblioteca es la que contiene libros (Es decir, sería el padre y los libros serían los hijos).

Entonces, como `Biblioteca` es una clase "padre" que se le asignarán "hijos" podemos crear un método para agregar libros a la lista de libros de la biblioteca. Este método `agregar_libro` recibirá elementos de tipo `Libro`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
class Libro():
    disponible= True
    def __init__ (self, titulo, autor, editorial, isbn, año_publicacion, num_ejemplares):
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.autor = autor
        self.editorial = editorial
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.año_publicacion = año_publicacion
        self.num_ejemplares = num_ejemplares
        print("Se ha registrado el libro", titulo)

    def prestar_libro(self):
        if self.num_ejemplares > 0:
            self.num_ejemplares = self.num_ejemplares -1
            print(f"Quedan disponibles:", self.num_ejemplares, "ejemplares de este libro.")
        if self.num_ejemplares == 0:
            print(f"No quedan disponibles ejemplares del libro", self.titulo)
            self.dispobible = False
        
    def devolver_libro(self):
        self.num_ejemplares = self.num_ejemplares + 1
        print(f"Cantidad de ejemplares disponibles: ", self.num_ejemplares)

    # Representación string de la clase
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Libro: {self.titulo}, con el autor: {self.autor}, y el editorial: {self.editorial}."

        
l = Libro ("Soy un libro", "Miqueas", "Santillana", 10402, 2023, 10)
print(l)

class Biblioteca():
    def __init__(self, lista_libros = None):
        if lista_libros is None:
            self.lista_libros = []
        else:
            self.lista_libros = lista_libros

    # Método para agregar libros a la lista de libros de la biblioteca
    def agregar_libro(self, libro):
        self.lista_libros.append(libro)

        
b = Biblioteca()
print(b.lista_libros)
b.agregar_libro(l)
print(b.lista_libros)
b.agregar_libro(Libro ("Soy otro libro", "Otro", "Santillana", 10402, 2023, 10))
print(b.lista_libros)
```

Esto imprime lo siguiente:

```
Se ha registrado el libro Soy un libro
Libro: Soy un libro, con el autor: Miqueas, y el editorial: Santillana.
[]
[Libro: Soy un libro, con el autor: Miqueas, y el editorial: Santillana.]
Se ha registrado el libro Soy otro libro
[Libro: Soy un libro, con el autor: Miqueas, y el editorial: Santillana., Libro: Soy otro libro, con el autor: Otro, y el editorial: Santillana.]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Heytale por el detalle y por corregir mi código, me ayudas bastante con esto de la POO, espero poder dominarla.